# Laravel Auth::login not respected

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, pusher

Im using a third party authentication service. When they have completed authenticating the user they will send a POST request to me at `auth/callback/{session}`. After confirming a valid request and fetching the associated `User` Im using `Auth::login($user)`, then broadcasting to pusher to let the frontend know it can redirect the user to `/dashboard`.

```
    public function callback($sessionId)
    {
        // ...

        if($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
        }

        broadcast(new CompletedThirdPartyAuthentication($sessionId));
    }
```

However, the user will not reach the dashboard but is redirected to `/login`. The `Auth::login` returns `null` though so I am assuming the login is successful. What have I missed? Or how can I debug further?

Also, this is the middleware on `/dashboard`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LoggedinMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        #if (!$request->user())
        $user = \Auth::user();
        if (!$user)
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### update

Im obviously confused about how sessions work: if I add an identic `GET` callback route and manually visit that in a new browser tab - it works. Something like: `https://app.test/auth/provider/callback/aosdvnapodvnaivnnodninasodvnnadvonon?id=asfbuauosfb`. It seems I can only use on the sessions from the same client. What are my alternatives here?

Answer (score 0):

Api-routes usually uses another driver then web-routes. So the authentication made under api-routes won't work under web-routes. Change settings in `config/auth.php` to use the same driver (session).

[See docs for auth](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

Comment: Thanks, in my case the API had zero middleware, just a prefix, anyways moved it outside to be sure.